# How to update a table column with another table column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table `Student` with columns `StudentID` (primary key), `Name`, `Active` and another table `Class` with columns `ClassID`, `StudentID` (foreign key from `Student`).

I need to update the table `Class` with `StudentID` which is having value 1 in column `Active` in `Student` table .

**Student**:

```
studentID   Name   Active
-------------------------
101         abc      0
102         abc      1
103         abc      0
```

**Class**:

```
ClassID  StudentID
------------------
  51       101
  52       102
  53       103
```

I need to update the table `Class` with StudentID 102 whose Active value is 1.

So final result in table `Class` is

```
ClassID  StudentID
------------------
  51       102
  52       102
  53       102
```

Comment: So all students in `Class` will be overridden with the only active student in `Student`? Strange requirement. If there are ten different students in class, afterwards there are ten students with the same ID?

Comment: @TimSchmelter.... In student table student abc is duplicated 3 times. so we are filtering it with Active column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to join both tables via `StudentId` but update the `StudentId` with the only active `StudentID` in the `Student`-table grouped by `Name`?

Then this should do the job:

```
WITH ContainsActiveStudentName AS
(
    SELECT s.studentID AS StudentId, s.Name, s.Active,
           ActiveStudentID = ( SELECT TOP 1 s2.StudentID FROM Student s2 
                               WHERE s.Name = s2.Name AND s2.Active = 1)
    FROM Student s
    WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM Student s2
                  WHERE s.Name = s2.Name AND s2.Active = 1)
)
UPDATE c SET c.StudentID = casn.ActiveStudentID
FROM Class c
INNER JOIN ContainsActiveStudentName casn ON c.StudentId = casn.StudentId
```

Here's a [sql-fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c76ae/5/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
Update Class 
join Student on Class.StudentID = Student.studentID 
set Class.StudentID = Student.studentID 
where Student.studentID = 1
```

Comment: I have not tested the query , I just turn its need for sql query